# history of patches' payments in Netlogo - Spatial PD

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am new to Netlogo and would appreciate some help!

Game:
I have green (cooperator) patches and 1 black (defector) patch. Their strategy is fixed by the color. Patches pick opponent one-of neighbors, play a game and get their payoff. Later they change their strategy to the strategy of the patch with the highest payoff over a number of the games within the agentset (highest gain).

I have a slider in the interface called "history" which tells the number of games for which the values of "payoff" should be stored.

**How should I write my "gain" procedure which will let me compute the payoff depending on a value of history?**

Comment: One way would create a patch variable to store this information (for example, called 'history') and store it as a list of pairs of strategy and payoff.   Then you would take the maximum payoff in that list and find the paired strategy. On a separate issue, you should almost certainly be using turtles rather than patches as players.

Comment: @JenB thank you! I had a model with turtles as agents already, just wanted to try something different